# Is there an algorithm that can be parallelized for the "unique" problem?

Tags: python-3.x, graphics

We have a long (about 100,000) two-dimension numpy array.
Like:

A_in =

[[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, …, 100000],

[2, 3, 3, 5, 4, 3, 1, …, 100000]] (edge_index_cpu in code)

You can treat one column as one group here. Every number means a point, one column means the line between these two points.

We need get output, like:

A_out =

[image] (new_edge_indices in code)

and index of these output values in the original array, like:

Idx_out =
[0, 2, 3]

The output group cannot any intersection with all the previous groups. In addition, if the previous group has been removed (like [[2],[3]] above), then the removed group will not be used to calculate the intersection (thus, [[3], [3]] is kept).

It can be easily implemented with a for loop. But because the data is too large for ‘for loop’, we would like to ask for an algorithm that can be parallelized for this problem.

I have tried to use numpy's unique operator from a flatten version of A_in 
([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, …]). But it cannot meet this “if the previous group has been removed (like [[2],[3]] above), then the removed group will not be used to calculate the intersection (thus, [[3], [3]] is kept)”.

We want to handle a graph containing edges and points.

```
    edge_index_cpu = edge_index.cpu()
    for edge_idx in edge_argsort.tolist():
        source = edge_index_cpu[0, edge_idx].item()
        if source not in nodes_remaining:
            continue

        target = edge_index_cpu[1, edge_idx].item()
        if target not in nodes_remaining:
            continue

        new_edge_indices.append(edge_idx)

        cluster[source] = i
        nodes_remaining.remove(source)

        if source != target:
            cluster[target] = i
            nodes_remaining.remove(target)

        i += 1

    # The remaining nodes are simply kept.
    for node_idx in nodes_remaining:
        cluster[node_idx] = i
        i += 1
    cluster = cluster.to(x.device)
```

Comment: assuming 32bit non negative integers indexes up to 1000000 (probably much less) so Why not use histogram marking used points converting your problem to single `O(n)` `for` loop ? You just need a histogram table containing single integer (or just bit) for each possible point index so `hist[1000000]` ... That should be fast so no parallelization needed ... in  a C++ on a standard PC I expect it should take up to 1 sec maybe even less ... I do not code in Python would a C++ example help?

Comment: @Spektre Thank you. I don't understand your idea, would you mind give some more detailed explanatio? There are 100 characters (10000 vertex per character), only 12 characters are processed at once. You could consider 100,000 rather than 1 million.

Comment: @Spektre Every character from CG movies or games containing about 10,000 vertex. I use these vertex to build graphs and feed these graphs into a graph neural network. Looking forward to your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not parallelize just yet as your problem can be solved in `O(n)`which should be fast enough.

1. **definitions**

   lets consider we got this:

   ```cpp
   const int pnts=1000000; // max points
   const int lins=1000000; // number of lines
   int lin[2][lins];       // lines
   bool his[pnts];         // histogram of points (used edge?)
   int out[pnts],outs=0;   // result out[outs]
   ```

   I am C++/GL oriented so I use indexes starting from zero !!! I used static arrays not to confuse with dynamic allocation or list templates so its easy to understand.
2. **histogram**

   create histogram for the points used. Its simply a table holding one counter or value per each possible point index. At start clear it. As we do not need to know how many times point is used I chose `bool` so its just `true/false` value that tells us if point is already used or not.

   so clear this table at start with `false`:

   ```cpp
   for (i=0;i<pnts;i++) his[i]=0;
   ```
3. **process lines data**

   simply process all points/lines in their order and update histogram for each point. So take a points index `p0/p1` from `lin[0/1][i]` and test if the both point are already used:

   ```cpp
   p0=lin[0][i];
   p1=lin[1][i];
   if ((!his[p0])&&(!his[p1])){ his[p0]=true; his[p1]=true; add i to result }
   ```

   if they are not add `i` to the result and set `p0,p1` as used in histogram. As you can see this is `O(1)` I assume you where using for loop linear search for now making your version `O(n^2)`.

**Here small `O(n)` C++ example for this (sorry not a python coder):**

```cpp
void compute()
    {
    const int pnts=1000000;     // max points
    const int lins=1000000;     // number of lines
    int lin[2][lins];           // lines
    bool his[pnts];             // histogram of points (used edge?)
    int out[pnts],outs=0;       // result out[outs]   
    int i,p0,p1;

    // generate data
    Randomize();
    for (i=0;i<lins;i++)
        {
        lin[0][i]=Random(pnts);
        lin[1][i]=Random(pnts);
        }
    // clear histogram
    for (i=0;i<pnts;i++) his[i]=0;
    // compute result O(lins)
    for (i=0;i<lins;i++)    // process all lines
        {
        p0=lin[0][i];       // first point of line
        p1=lin[1][i];       // second point of line
        if ((!his[p0])&&(!his[p1])) // both unused yet?
            {
            his[p0]=true;   // set them as used
            his[p1]=true;
            out[outs]=i;    // add new edge to result list
            outs++;
            }
        }
    // here out[outs] holds the result
    }
```

runtime is linear and on my machine it took ~10ms so no need for parallelization.

In case `bool` is not a single bit you can pack the histogram into unsigned integers using its bits (for example pack 32 points into single 32 bit int variable) to preserve memory. In such case 1M points results in 125000 Bytes table which is not a problem these days

When I feed your data to the code:

```
int lin[2][lins]=       // lines
    {
    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1 },
    { 2, 3, 3, 5, 4, 3, 1 },
    };
```

I got this result:

```
{ 0, 2, 3 }
```

Comment: Seems like there is a huge speed difference between python and cpp when processing a big for-loop. Maybe I should rewrite this part in C. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @RuiShi Python is one of the slowest languages ... IIRC its interpreted speed is done by using C++ created stuff (libs packages) called from it.  What about the result difference which one is correct? mine or yours so I can update code its just matter of  `if` condition

Comment: Why there is a 7 in your result? And, note that, column (2, 3) should be removed, but column (3, 3) is kept.

Comment: when add an edge index i into the result, you need make sure both the two points have not been used in previous. Not just one of these two. I think the next thing I need to do is implementing this part code with cpp. Python is too slow here.

Comment: I don't have the github url for now. The code is one part of a graph pooling method. (Named edge pooling)

Comment: @RuiShi done ... You should add the description that both edges must be unused to your question too (if it is not there already and I just overlook it). The runtime is the same ~10ms ...